# Can you delete workspace after building/INSTALLING from source?

Tags: ros, build-from-source, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I built ROS from source on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Raspberry Pi OS (32 bit Raspbian Buster), using the command:

```
sudo src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/noetic -j1 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
```

Since I have installed to the normal directory where ROS would reside if I had installed it from the binary repository, can I safely delete the workspace and continue using ROS ?  I experimented renaming the workspace and could still use roscd and roscore.  Are there any problems which could show up later ?

I favour doing this to save space on the sd card, and also because catkin_make_isolated wants to rebuild everything even if only my own projects change (I could solve that with an overlay, but it seems cleaner just to lose the initial workspace).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376017/can-you-delete-workspace-after-building/installing-from-source-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can you delete workspace after building/INSTALLING from source ?

the short answer would be: yes, you can delete the bootstrap workspace after you've ran `catkin_make_isolated --install`.

> Are there any problems which could show up later ?

I don't know about *problems* per se, but not having your sources around will make it more difficult to [Maintain[ing] [your] Source Checkout](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Source#Maintaining_a_Source_Checkout).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2021-04-14**:
Thanks for the reassurance.  I deleted the directory and so far everything still works.  It is convenient because now I don't need overlayed workspaces.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-14**:
You're still executing `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`, aren't you?

With that command, you're essentially `source`-ing the `install` space of the underlay in `/opt/ros/noetic`.

There's nothing really special about the files in `/opt/ros`, it's the same structure as the `install` space in one of "your own" workspaces.